# javascript use named function as method in an object

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I have an object, lets call it myObject, and a named function myFunction.

Can I create a method in myObject, lets call it myMethod, so that whenever I call myObject.myMethod I'll actually call myFunction.

I know i can create a new function for myMethod, and probably could make it be a wrappeI for myFunction, but is there a better way? or am I doing this all wrong

Comment: *"am I doing this all wrong"* - You should explain the reason why you would like to do this for an answer to that question.

Comment: yes you can, have you tried assigning it into the object?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? `myObject.myMethod = myFunction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is all you need to :

```
var myObject = {};
var myFunction =  function() {/* code goes here*/};

myObject.myMethod = myFunction;
```

Because of how JavaScript works, though, this wouldn't become an object-specific function this way, so you couldn't track state with it. It would be similar to a static function in Java.

Comment: It would work just the same way. Give it a shot and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

i think you are confusing your words. methods of an object are generally functions. like so-:

```
var myObject = {
x:0,
y:0,
getX: function () {
     return this.x;
    },
getY: function () {
     return this.y;
    }
};
```

you can add any number of methods/functions.